# Facing Issues while commiting data on solr 6.4.2

Tags: java, solr, lucene, garbage-collection, solrj

I am indexing data close to 45 Million . Documents on solr 6.4.2 . Primarily it consists e of close to 80 odd fields of which some are large text fields and some are very large fields(articles or reports). All three cores are on single solr instance . I am facing issues with commit of data on one core (the core which is master core has 50% of documents) . It takes some hours to commit data and rest are working fine . all Have same config . cofig parameters are all default with atocmommit, softcommit,tlog disabled. Please It will be really helpful if you could point me to a direction to look .

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a version mismatch in the custom filter factory which was compiled using 6.4.1 which was causing the delay in the addition of documents.I recompiled
it with 6.4.2 and it was working as expected.